# Fill a second/third levels of nested accordion dynamically

Tags: reactjs, accordion, semantic-ui-react

I need to fill a second & **third** levels of nested accordion (from semantic-ui-react) and this is how I tried to implement it:

```
let lvl1Items = [];
let lvl2Items = [];
let lvl1Content;
let lvl2Content;


function handleOnItemTitleClickedLevel1(e, itemProps) {
//console.log("======>", e.currentTarget.textContent);
//let selected = e.currentTarget.textContent;

console.log(itemProps.index);
const index = itemProps.index;
lvl2Items = [];

elementsLevel2.forEach(function(item) {
    lvl2Items.push(
        {key: item.Name, title: item.Name, content: ''}
    )
});

lvl1Content = (
    <div>
        <Accordion.Accordion panels={lvl2Items} onTitleClick={handleOnItemTitleClickedLevel2} />
    </div>
)

//this.state.lvl1Items.forEach( (item) => item.key === selected ? 
item.content = {content : this.state.lvl2Items})
lvl1Items[index].content = {content : lvl1Content};
}

function handleOnItemTitleClickedLevel2(e, itemProps) {
console.log(itemProps.index);
const index = itemProps.index;
const lvl3Items = [];

elementsLevel3.forEach(function(item) {
    lvl3Items.push(
        {key: item.Name, title: item.Name, content: ''}
    )
});
console.log(lvl3Items);
lvl2Content = (
    <div>
        <Accordion.Accordio panels={lvl3Items} />
    </div>
)

lvl2Items[index].content = {content : lvl2Content};
}

class ProjectCustomize extends Component {

state = {
    //activeIndex: 0,
    // lvl1Items : [],
    // lvl2Items : [],
    // lvl3Items : []
}

componentDidMount() {
    lvl1Items = [];
    elementsLevel1.forEach(function(item) {
        lvl1Items.push(
            {key: item.Name, title: item.Name, content: lvl1Content}
        )
    });
}

render() {
    //const { lvl1Items, lvl2Items, lvl3Items } = this.state;

    //const lvl1Items = [];
    // const lvl2Items = [];
    // const lvl3Items = [];

    return (
        <Tabs>

            <Tab label="Quantities">


                                {/*<Accordion>*/}
                                {/*    {lvl1Items}*/}
                                {/*</Accordion>*/}

                               <Accordion /*defaultActiveIndex={0}*/ /*activeIndex={activeIndex}*/  panels={lvl1Items} styled onTitleClick={this.handleOnItemTitleClickedLevel1} />


            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
}
}
```

I'm new to react, is it the correct way to do it? maybe to use state instead of global variables?
............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Hi mate, I've recently built an accordion on top of react-router-dom and react-semantic-ui, checkout the source, it's very basic and coincise https://github.com/bionicvapourboy/react-semantic-ui-accordion-menu

Comment: Thanks. I took a look, but in my case the tree is not populated at once... only when clicking on one level I'll get the values of it's children (by demand)

Comment: The menu is fed by a json array that can be returned by a function, so it can be dynamic

Comment: Does your component has MIT or Apache license? Otherwise I can't use it :~
My problem currently with the semantic component is displaying third level, when using <Accordion.Accordion for third level it didn't work! How did you manage to come over it? is it supported by default for their component?

Comment: My component is without any license right now, as you can see from source it relies on panels and content, with recursion. Like the example in semantic ui react docs

Comment: I took a look at your code, but I don't want to implement my own creating panels and handling recursion divs.. I want to use something already exist and I'm not getting help from sematic till now... taking a look at my code, can you see where is the problem of displaying third level?

Comment: First, there is a typo <Accordion.Accordio panels={lvl3Items} />. "Accordio" instead of "Accordion"

Comment: Yes it's due to copy paste - I noticed it, but the code is fine... I even tried with <Accordion and not <Accordion.Accordion and I had the same result! My concern is that because I'm not using a state variable when binding the Accordion it's not reflected for third level (but changes were reflected on second level!)

Comment: Can you post a working snippet on stackblitz ?

Comment: I found my issue. removed the onTitleClick from:   {key: item.Name, title: item.Name, content: '' /*, onTitleClick: handleOnItemTitleClickedLevel2*/}, it shouldn't be here. I put it there while I was testing and trying and forgot to remove it.